# Interpolate between pixels on an image

Tags: java, image-processing, interpolation

I'm trying to implement a way to sample a texture in Java. I want this to work the same way it would by using GLSL's "texture" function. I want the neighboring pixels to be taken into account when the color is calcuated.

For example, say I use a float to get the image color at a certain pixel, and the number falls between two pixels. How can I calculate a mix of the neighboring pixels? Here's an image showing my goal.

[image]

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this using java's BufferedImage class?

Here's the code I have so far, it only works for the x position at the moment.

```
public static final java.awt.Color getColor(final BufferedImage image, final float x, final int y) {

    final float imageX = x * image.getWidth();

    final float decimal = imageX % 1f;

    final java.awt.Color left = new java.awt.Color(image.getRGB(Maths.clamp((int) imageX - 1, 0, image.getWidth() - 1), y));
    final java.awt.Color center = new java.awt.Color(image.getRGB(Maths.clamp((int) imageX, 0, image.getWidth() - 1), y));
    final java.awt.Color right = new java.awt.Color(image.getRGB(Maths.clamp((int) imageX + 1, 0, image.getWidth() - 1), y));

    if (decimal == 0.5f) return center;

    if (decimal < 0.5f) {

        final float distanceFromCenter = 0.5f - decimal;
        final float distanceFromLeft = decimal + 0.5f;

        final Vector3f leftColor = new Vector3f(left.getRed() / 255f, left.getGreen() / 255f, left.getBlue() / 255f);
        final Vector3f centerColor = new Vector3f(center.getRed() / 255f, center.getGreen() / 255f, center.getBlue() / 255f);

        leftColor.scale(1f - distanceFromLeft);
        centerColor.scale(1f - distanceFromCenter);

        final Vector3f color = Vector3f.add(leftColor, centerColor, null);

        return new java.awt.Color(color.getX(), color.getY(), color.getZ());

    } else {

        final float distanceFromCenter = decimal - 0.5f;
        final float distanceFromRight = 1f - decimal + 0.5f;

        final Vector3f rightColor = new Vector3f(right.getRed() / 255f, right.getGreen() / 255f, right.getBlue() / 255f);
        final Vector3f centerColor = new Vector3f(center.getRed() / 255f, center.getGreen() / 255f, center.getBlue() / 255f);

        rightColor.scale(1f - distanceFromRight);
        centerColor.scale(1f - distanceFromCenter);

        final Vector3f color = Vector3f.add(rightColor, centerColor, null);

        return new java.awt.Color(color.getX(), color.getY(), color.getZ());

    }

}
```

Comment: what exactly interpolate mean here? provide some code here as what is the problem and what you are trying achieve?

Comment: so you have image and you want to change their color through pixels?using buffered image?

Comment: I want to get the pixel color that **would** be there if the image were to be stretched, but without actually stretching the image.

Comment: below answer will do suffice..use it accordingly, especially take the pixels from image part..

Comment: are you using some wierd libraries? as far as i know Vector3f is used in java3d but I cant preclude others

Comment: I'm using LWJGL and my own library, named ASCL which is providing the "Maths" class.

Answer (score 0):

hope this code help, if you use this appropriately. This function extract pixels from buffered image and we can replace it what ever we want:

```
    private BufferedImage changeColor(BufferedImage image, int srcColor, int replaceColor)
{

    BufferedImage destImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = destImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, null, 0, 0);
    g.dispose();


    for (int width = 0; width < image.getWidth(); width++)
    {
        for (int height = 0; height < image.getHeight(); height++)
        {

           if (destImage.getRGB(width, height) == srcColor)
            {
               destImage.setRGB(width, height, replaceColor);
            }

        }
    }

    return destImage;
}
```

Comment: did you get the out come or what? if it is make this is answered or share your code and problem..

Comment: I think I got you confused... I don't want to replace any colors, I want this to get a pixel out of the image using bilinear filtering

Comment: pixels are actual colors of image. if you want to take out of pixels from image and it obvious that image going to lose the color!! or you just want find the pixels used in image?